# jq include default search path

Tags: jq, module-search-path

I would like to put a function definition in /usr/lib/jq/mytest.jq to be included in my jq script.

From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Modules)  :

> The default search path is the search path given to the -L
>   command-line option, else ["~/.jq", "$ORIGIN/../lib/jq",
>   "$ORIGIN/../lib"].

Since jq is in /usr/bin shouldn't /usr/bin/../lib/jq be in the search path? I can't get this command to work:

```
jq -n 'include "mytest";'
```

Adding -L /usr/lib/jq to the command works, or I can create a ~/.jq/mytest.jq and that works as well.  However, I'd like to use the ~/.jq file for startup.  How can I have a startup script *and* a include search path without specifying -L on the command line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have a startup script and a include search path without specifying -L on the command line?

Use the module metadata feature, e.g.:

```
include "mytest" {"search": "/usr/local/lib/jq"};
```

### Illustration

```
$ cat /usr/local/lib/jq/mytest.jq
def go: "hello";

$ jq -n 'include "mytest" {"search": "/usr/local/lib/jq"}; go'
"hello"
```

### Postscript

If you believe there is a mismatch between the current version of jq (1.6) and the corresponding documentation at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/
please file a report at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues

Comment: It seems to me that Issue #1666 does not completely cover the range of issues you've encountered.